# How to create this model meta method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods

I used to have the following model method, which I called upon using `if @invitation.invite_expired? ...`:

```
def invite_expired?
  cycle_invite_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
end
```

Because I want to use this method for multiple expiration checks I have tried to create a "meta" method as follows:

```
def expired?(what)
  check = send("#{what}_invite_sent_at")
  check < 2.hours.ago     #Also tried "self.check" but that made no difference.
end
```

I call upon this method using: `if @invitation.expired?(cycle) ...`. However, now all sorts of tests fail with the message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `cycle' for #<InvitationsController:0x0000000a5e8d50>
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It says "undefined local variable or method \`cycle'", so the first question is: is there a local variable or method named `cycle`? If there isn't, you need to define it. If there is, the next question is: what scope is it defined in and what scope are you trying to use it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it like:

```
if @invitation.expired?("cycle")
  # some code here.
```

I assume this because `undefined local variable or method 'cycle'` raised in the controller code, it happens, when you try to use plain `cycle` instead of a string `"cycle"`.